# split an element in list of lists to new element

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of lists like the following:

```
lofl = [['3_A', '1_E'], ['1_A', '1_C,1_B'], ['1_B', '1_C']]
```

I want to check each element and deflate the second element into ['1_A','1_C','1_B']. So that, my final output is

```
lofl = [['3_A', '1_E'], ['1_A', '1_C', '1_B'], ['1_B', '1_C']]
```

I tried the following but it did not work.

```
deflate = [i for i in tre_exr for j in i str(i).split(",")]
```

I get invalid syntax. Can anyone suggest where the problem is ?

Thanks in advance.

Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close, you just somehow mixed in a superfluous `i` in the list comprehension; also, in the end (i.e. at the beginning of the list comprehension) you want the "inner" `j`, not the "outer" `i`. Also, not necessary to convert to `str`:

```
[ j for i in tre_exr for j in i.split(",") ]
```

For your entire list of lists, you have to wrap that into another list comprehension:

```
>>> lofl = [['3_A', '1_E'], ['1_A', '1_C,1_B'], ['1_B', '1_C']]
>>> [[j for i in tre_exr for j in i.split(",")] for tre_exr in lofl]
[['3_A', '1_E'], ['1_A', '1_C', '1_B'], ['1_B', '1_C']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Im kinda new to python so this took a little bit of figuring out! See below for the most concise soloution I could think of.

```
import itertools
lofl = [['3_A', '1_E'], ['1_A', '1_C,1_B'], ['1_B', '1_C']]

new = [list(itertools.chain(*[c.split(',') for c in l])) for l in lofl]

print new
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is the way to go if you want an "easy to read" solution.

```
lofl = [['3_A', '1_E'], ['1_A', '1_C,1_B'], ['1_B', '1_C']]

result = []
for item in lofl:
    x = []
    for i in item:
        x += i.split(',')
    result.append(x)

>>> result
[['3_A', '1_E'], ['1_A', '1_C', '1_B'], ['1_B', '1_C']]
```